# Misunderstanding Go Language specification on floating-point rounding

Tags: go, constants, constant-expression

The Go language specification on the section about [Constant expressions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Constant_expressions) states:

> A compiler may use rounding while computing untyped floating-point or complex constant expressions; see the implementation restriction in the section on constants. This rounding may cause a floating-point constant expression to be invalid in an integer context, even if it would be integral when calculated using infinite precision, and vice versa.

---

Does the sentence

> This rounding may cause a floating-point constant expression to be invalid in an integer context

point to something like the following:

```golang
func main() {
    a := 853784574674.23846278367
    fmt.Println(int8(a)) // output: 0
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quoted part from the spec does not apply to your example, as `a` is not a constant expression but a variable, so `int8(a)` is converting a non-constant expression. This conversion is covered by [Spec: Conversions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions), Conversions between numeric types:

> When converting a [floating-point number](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Numeric_types) to an integer, the fraction is discarded (truncation towards zero).
>
> [...] In all non-constant conversions involving floating-point or complex values, if the result type cannot represent the value the conversion succeeds but the result value is implementation-dependent.

Since you convert a non-constant expression `a` being `853784574674.23846278367` to an integer, the fraction part is discarded, and since the result does not fit into an `int8`, the result is not specified, it's implementation-dependent.

The quoted part means that while constants are represented with a lot higher precision than the builtin types (eg. `float64` or `int64`), the precision that a compiler (have to) implement is not infinite (for practical reasons), and even if a floating point literal is representable precisely, performing operations on them may be carried out with intermediate roundings and may not give mathematically correct result.

[The spec includes the minimum supportable precision:](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Constants)

> Implementation restriction: Although numeric constants have arbitrary precision in the language, a compiler may implement them using an internal representation with limited precision. That said, every implementation must:
>
> - Represent integer constants with at least 256 bits.
> - Represent floating-point constants, including the parts of a complex constant, with a mantissa of at least 256 bits and a signed binary exponent of at least 16 bits.
> - Give an error if unable to represent an integer constant precisely.
> - Give an error if unable to represent a floating-point or complex constant due to overflow.
> - Round to the nearest representable constant if unable to represent a floating-point or complex constant due to limits on precision.

For example:

```
const (
    x = 1e100000 + 1
    y = 1e100000
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(x - y)
}
```

This code should output `1` as `x` is being 1 larger than `y`. Running it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/6Q49Onp55XR) outputs `0` because the constant expression `x - y` is executed with roundings, and the `+1` is lost as a result. Both `x` and `y` are integers (have no fraction part), so in integer context the result should be `1`. But the number being `1e100000`, representing it requires around ~333000 bits, which is not a valid requirement from a compiler (according to the spec, 256 bit mantissa is sufficient).

If we lower the constants, we get correct result:

```
const (
    x = 1e1000 + 1
    y = 1e1000
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(x - y)
}
```

This outputs the mathematically correct `1` result. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/FQdZZ35RXv3). Representing the number `1e1000` requires around ~3333 bits which seems to be supported (and it's way above the minimum 256 bit requirement).

Answer (score 0):

An int8 is a signed integer, and can have a value from -128 to 127. That's why you are seeing unexpected value with **int8(a)** conversion.